# git, dot-git folder and other files found in home folder?

Tags: git

On a Mac used for Unity development, it's all svn, but there's **only one** folder used with a server git repo, /User/myname/clients/blah/project

Now I happened to be using Android Studio and (like most IDEs now) it tries to do source control for you.  I got a pop up alerting me there is an "unregistered source", in fact at my home folder.

So at /User/myname I found these files ..

```
$ ls -la
.git
.gitconfig
.gitignore_global
```

Well now, in the folder under source control /User/myname/clients/blah/project there is indeed

```
$ ls -la
.git
.svn
```

and it all works great.

The text file ".gitconfig" appears to have my password, etc, for logging in to the server in question for the repo of /User/myname/clients/blah/project.

What I don't understand:

Can I **just get rid** of the .git directory **in my home directory**?

(Perhaps, I just accidentally started a git there or something?)

Or indeed, does Git "need" a .git folder in your home directory, **as well as** a .git directory in the folder under control?

Or, do I not understand "unregistered source" - ?

Specifically, would it be safe and harmless to delete that .git folder in the **home** directory ?

Further, Git seems to have chosen to use my "home" directory for preferences/etc rather than the folder /User/myname/clients/blah/project where I was actually using it. Is that my stuff up or is it just what Git does?

---

Based on the incredible answer below, I went to the **home** directory, and

```
$ git log
```

and got this:

```
fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet
```

When I "git log" in the /User/myname/clients/blah/project directory, it indeed shows a long list of commits which I did for that project over the years.

Does this suggest I can just plain delete the .git folder in the **home** directory?

Comment: to your edit: Yes, that's what I meant with "If it's empty". You can just delete the `.git` folder in your home directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The `.git` directory in your home folder

It is not required.

I'm using git heavily and git didn't create that directory on my machine. Before deleting it, I would recommend you to look whats inside the git repository, by executing `git log`. If it's empty, it is safe to delete it. If it's not empty, you can create a new clone by doing `git clone $HOME/.git strangerepo`. Then, look at the folder `strangerepo` to see the content of the git repo.

**EDIT**: Keep in mind that the working directory is relevant when executing the git command. If git is not currently inside a git repository, it will go to the parent directory and search for a `.git` folder there. When it reaches `/`, it will output an error that no repository was found. So executing `git log` in `$HOME` will have a different result than running it in `$HOME/path/to/your/repo`.

### The `.gitconfig` file

Don't delete it. Git uses it.

To use git, you need to tell git your name and your email. You do so with commands that look like that:

```
git config --global what.ever value
```

These config is saved in `$HOME/.gitconfig`. If you call `git config` without the `--global` flag (inside a git repo directory), git will only save the config for the specific repository. But of course this file does not need to contain your password - a file looking like this is just fine:

```
[user]
    email = you@example.com
    name= XYZ
```

Comment: You are incredibly knowledgeable!  Thank you so much.  TBC, doing "git log" is relevant to the DIRECTORY YOU ARE IN, right? I have done what you recommend; results edited in to the question!   It looks like I can probably just delete that .git folder then?

Comment: @JoeBlow I have added some info for the working directory of git

Comment: Thank you so much - I'm sure this post will be extremely valuable to very many googlers over the years going forward, great stuff. I'd not found this explained clearly anywhere else, cheers